# Как найти родительский раздел по массиву и снова записть его в массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив $vid[]
Который выглядит к примеру так

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Название 1 
        [select] => Array (
            [0] => 406
            [1] => 407
            [5] => 469
        )
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => Название 2 
        [select] => Array (
            [0] => 390
            [1] => 396
            [2] => 469
        )
    )
)
```

В таблице есть Столбец с ParentID - родительский раздел

получается к примеру у раздела

406, 407 - родитель 1000

469 - родитель 1001

390, 369 - родитель 1002

В итоге должен получиться такой массив

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Название 1 
        [parent_id] => Array (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 1001
        )
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => Название 2 
        [parent_id] => Array (
            [0] => 1002
            [1] => 1001
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: ParentID с воздуха мы должны взять? откуда он получится, где его посмотреть?

Comment: Я же написал все, SubID = > 406, ParentID = > 1000; SubID => 407, ParentID = > 1000; SubID => 469, ParentID = > 1001 и т.д.

Comment: Если описать точнее, то есть таблица Subdivision где есть SubID и ParentID, и есть таблица Video там есть Select. В Select записываются SubID (406,407,469 - т.е. к в вопросе). В итоге по Select мне нужно найти все SubID в таблице Subdivision и вывести их родителей ParentID, все повторяющиеся ParentID объединить, выводить только уникальные. Как то так.